# Как можно сделать динамический IP на amazon aws или смена elastic ip программно?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, amazon

В aws.amazon в панели управления инстансом можно изменять свой elastic (public) IP и подключать его к своему инстансу.

Как можно программно это реализовать?

Система Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

инструменты командной строки:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ami-tools.html

получить новый IP - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AllocateAddress.html

привязать IP к серверу - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AssociateAddress.html

отвязать от сервера - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DisassociateAddress.html

освободить адрес - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ReleaseAddress.html